# Transferring std::unique_ptr between Widgets

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a Widget class, which is supposed to have unique ownership of another Widget.
I want to implement a function which passes this Widget to another Widget. I learnt that the best way to implement the concept of single ownership is `std::unique_ptr`, however I can't get it to run

This is the code:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(void) { }
    virtual ~Widget(void) { /* */ }
    void successor(Widget&& successor)
    {
        this->_successor = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(&successor);
    }
    void refer_value(int a)
    {
        _successor->value = a;  
    }
    auto refer_value(void) const -> int
    {
        return _successor->value;
    }
    auto get(void) -> Widget&
    {
        return *_successor;
    }

    int value;
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Widget> _successor;
};
```

It compiles without a problem, but when I try to run this:

```
int main(void)
{
    Widget a{};
    Widget b{};
    Widget c{};

    a.successor(Widget{});
    a.refer_value(5);

    b.successor(std::move(a.get()));
    std::cout << b.refer_value();
}
```

I get a Segmentation Fault. What is the problem?

And additionally, How would I have to write an implementation of the successor() function, if I wanted to pass `Widget c`. I could only get it running for rvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
this->_successor = std::unique_ptr<Widget>(&successor);
```

You're creating a `unique_ptr` to an object that would be destroyed once the scope exits.

Also, here

```
b.successor(std::move(a.get()));
```

You're taking the address of an existing pointer in a `unique_ptr`, and assigning it to *yet another* `unique_ptr`. It's basically wrong/double deallocations all over the place here.

I'm *highly* unaware of what you're trying to do here. At any rate, if I can just limit myself to the number of changes relevant to memory management here in order to have this code make sense:

```
class Widget
{
public:
    Widget(void) { }

    virtual ~Widget(void) { /* */ }

    void successor(std::shared_ptr<Widget> successor)
    {
        this->_successor = std::move(successor);
    }

    void refer_value(int a)
    {
        _successor->value = a;
    }

    auto refer_value(void) const -> int
    {
        return _successor->value;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Widget> get()
    {
        return _successor;
    }

    int value;

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> _successor;
};

int main(void)
{
    Widget a{};
    Widget b{};
    Widget c{};

    a.successor(std::make_shared<Widget>());
    a.refer_value(5);

    b.successor(a.get());
    std::cout << b.refer_value();
}
```

Comment: I want to guarantee, that no two Widgets point to the same Widget. However when I call `std::cout << a.refer_value();`  in your code I also get 5.

Comment: @henrikgiesel You could make `::get()` return `std::shared_ptr<Widget>&` and then `move()` it into `b.successor()`. However, then `a.refer_value()` would dereference a null pointer, so you have to watch out for that.

Comment: I think I could circumvent that by calling `operator bool` on the pointer. However I would still like a solution for `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: @henrikgiesel Then use `unique_ptr` just for ownership and raw pointers for referencing. However, note that then, when owning widgets go out of scope, raw pointers would still be accessible unless you do something about it. It seems better to use `shared_ptr` here.

Comment: @henrikgiesel >1 `unique_ptr`s pointing to same pointer --> time bomb